# How to Show Sql Results into Grid Column

Tags: php, html

i want to fetch post from database, i am able to fetch all the rows from database but how i can show them into template view, so it can show all the rows into that template.

here is my php query

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $q = "select title, image, summary, desc from posts";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //print_r($data);
?>
```

and i want to echo echo row data into this template view, how can i do this?

```
<!-- Grid column -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

    <!-- Featured image -->
    <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-2 mb-4">
        <a href="post/<?php echo $title; ?>"><img class="img-fluid" src="upload/<?php echo $image?>" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <a href=""><h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3"><strong><?php echo $list->title; ?></strong></h4></a>
    <p class="dark-grey-text"><?php echo $summary; ?></p>

</div>
<!-- Grid column -->
```

Comment: Little tip:
You can replace
`<?php echo $var; ?>` with `<?= $var ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use any framework you should write your HTML in the same file and foreach over your data:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $value) { ?>
<!-- Grid column -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

  <!-- Featured image -->
  <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-2 mb-4">
    <a href="post/<?php echo $value['title']; ?>"><img class="img-fluid" src="upload/<?php echo $value['image']?>" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <a href=""><h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3"><strong><?php echo $list->title; ?></strong></h4></a>
  <p class="dark-grey-text"><?php echo $value['summary']; ?></p>

</div>
<!-- Grid column -->
<?php } ?>
```